# VSTS Nested Variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to accomplish a cascading variable, where when one design time variable is set, it cascades to other variables.  Is this possible?  I've tried with dot notation, I've tried without dot notation, and I've tried to do it in the task:

[image: Dot Notation Variables]

[image: Not Dot Notation]

[image: Inside Task]

I also tried this task plugin, but my agents are on 2.0 and the task doesn't run.

[Variable Toolbox Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks)

Any ideas?

Answer:

You can override these variables at the environment level.  I will have to expand these variables in my script manually and then set them to the resolved values in this script.

Comment: It works fine for me: `Server: $(Server.$(Environment))`. How do you use `Server` variable? (I used it in argument of PowerShell task) What's the version of the agent version (Hosted agent and private agent (2.120.2) work fine)

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: @starain-MSFT yes, your answer will actually solve this issue, since I can write a program to pull the VSTS build variables from a script, then expand these variables myself in that script.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the variable value through [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) during the build:

1. Add PowerShell task

Script: (Need to use `_` instead if the variable contains `.`, such as Server.Dev=> Server_Dev)

```
$v= [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Server_$env:Environment")
Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=Server;]$v")
```

2. Then the following tasks could use Server variable with corresponding value

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having different variables for each environment, use the **same** variable but override it at the environment level.

Comment: This is a maintenance nightmare.