# Unable to read variable values at runtime in azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I have created a azure devops release pipeline. I am using this pipeline to install some prerequisites on server for an application.
While installing one of the prerequisites, I have a task (powershell script) which needs ChannelPrefix variable value.
I want to set it at runtime because that will depend on environment type for which I am building server.

At the moment I am unable to read the azure devops variable value the way I want.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you need to pass environment variables from one script to another, you can assign variables by printing / echoing text in a certain format. For example: `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=one]secondValue"` -- see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables

Comment: Hi James,

Thanks for your reply.

I am not using environment variable. Its custom defined variable that I am using. Also I am passing not passing its value between multiple scripts. 
It is just a single script to which I want to pass the value at runtime.

Comment: Did you link that variable group to release/build?

Comment: Yes I have linked it. Its just I am using nested thing to read value of variable at runtime

Comment: Nested variables are not yet supported in Azure pipelines, see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60430376/3537880) thread