# Powershell variable over azure devops variable

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to pass PowerShell variable to an Azure Devops variable in pipeline during runtime but unable to pass them successfully. Could someone guide the correct syntax to apply escape sequence?

**Azure devops pipeline variable:-**

```
foo_ABC = abcdefghigklmnopqrstxyz
env= abc
```

**Powershell task in pipeline:-**

```
$environment=  "$(env)".ToUpper()

$temp= "foo_$($environment)"

Write-Output "$($temp)"
```

**Output:-**

```
Expected: abcdefghigklmnopqrstxyz

Actual: (foo_ABC)
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for how Azure DevOps variables are treated in scripts? Hint: It's an environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue , the value of nested variables (like $($temp) are not yet supported in the pipelines. You can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194458/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-set-the-artifact-name-in-my-azure-devops-build-p/56215166#56215166) to see this point.

As a workaround, you can try to use the [Variable Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks) task.

[image]

[image]
[image]

You can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736978/vsts-nested-variables) for this task.